# Scan file with 3 possible regex in one method

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I am trying to retrive data from a folder which contains 3 .txt file (the same information) but in a different order.

The data that I need to get is : Date Text number (one ligne) 
But the structure of my file is unique for each of them

## file1 :

```
Date text
number
```

## file2 :

```
Date
Text number
```

## file3 :

```
Date
Text
number
```

Any suggestion !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern should be alright:

`(?i)(date)(?:\/|\s*)(text)(?:\/|\s*)(number)`

Java string in code:

```
 var pattern = "(?i)(date)(?:\\/|\\s*)(text)(?:\\/|\\s*)(number)";
```

Output:

```
Match 1:    
    0: [11,32] Date/text number
    1: [11,15] Date
    2: [16,20] text
    3: [26,32] number
Match 2:
    0: [45,66] Date Text/number
    1: [45,49] Date
    2: [55,59] Text
    3: [60,66] number
Match 3:
    0: [81,107] Date Text number
    1: [81,85] Date
    2: [91,95] Text
    3: [101,107] number
```

Comment: but one regular expression cannot match all the result !

Answer (score 0):

```
(Date)\/?\s*(text)\/?\s*(number)
```

Try this.grab group 1,2,3 .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/22